# Disconnecting graph (and subgraphs) by removing fewest amount of edges - NP completeness

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete

I am trying to prove that a certain problem is $NP$-complete. The problem is that in a given order of elements like $(a>b>c)$, $(c>d>b>a)$, there will be inconsistencies. From these orders, you can conclude that $a>a$, which is an inconsistency. Removing all inconsistencies by removing the fewest amount of orders is the problem.

After thinking about this for quite some time, I thought this problem can also be viewed as a directed graph, where each edge is an order. If the graph is connected (you can traverse from vertex $A$ back to vertex $A$), it has at least one inconsistency. Removing the strong-connectivity of the graph would remove the inconsistency, right? Well, there's still the subgraphs that might be connected (moving from one vertex back to itself while not traversing all vertices), so that would have to be dealt with as well. Removing all the strong-connectivity by removing the fewest edges possible should be an accurate interpretation of the problem, but I am not sure.

So, at this point my question is, first of all, is my directed graph example an accurate interpretation of the problem? If it is, is there any $NP$-complete problem that can be used in a reduction to this problem? Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Your problem seems related to [Feedback Vertex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set). Perhaps the NP-hardness proof of this problem can give you more ideas. Maybe reducing from it is even possible by creating an additional vertex  to represent the edges.

Comment: Your problem seems to be [Feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set).

Comment: I'm rusty on my graph terminology, the "connected subgraphs" I described are actually just called cycles. What I  described is the exact Minimal Feedback Arc Set problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Removing the fewest number of edges to make a graph disconnected can be solved with max flow/min cut in polynomial time.